# How to publish events in azure event grid to a topic in python?

Tags: python, azure-eventgrid, azure-python-sdk

Unable to import the eventgrid modules in my VS Code, I have added all the modules in requirement.txt and pip installed from my cmd.

Also, below is the python function which I am looking and trying with:

```
def publish_event(): 
    # authenticate client 
    credential = AzureKeyCredential(key) 
    client = EventGridPublisherClient(endpoint, credential) 
 
    custom_schema_event = { 
        "customSubject": "sample", 
        "customEventType": "sample.event", 
        "customDataVersion": "2.0", 
        "customId": uuid.uuid4(), 
        "customEventTime": dt.datetime.now(UTC()).isoformat(), 
        "customData": "sample data" 
    } 
 
    # publish events 
    for _  in range(3): 
 
        event_list = []     # list of events to publish 
        # create events and append to list 
        for j in range(randint(1, 3)): 
            event_list.append(custom_schema_event) 
 
        # publish list of events 
        client.send(event_list) 
        print("Batch of size {} published".format(len(event_list))) 
        time.sleep(randint(1, 5)) 
 
 
if name == '__main__': 
    publish_event()
```

I am not sure whether this is the correct method to achieve this, looking for better ways to solve the module issue and to publish events.

Help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question we can see there are two points which needs to be answered:

1. Python packages installation issue
2. Eventgrid topic issue

- For installing Azure Python packages with pip install, we need to enable virtual environment in our terminal, commands are as follows:

  ```
     python -m venv .venv
    .venv\Scripts\activate
  ```

  After enabling the venv, add all eventgrid, storage and other azure related  packages in requirements.txt, then run below command in cmd:

  > pip install -r requirements.txt
- Now, looking at your code, function looks fine as it is sending the events to a general topic. In a similar way we have a sample which gives us some insight about publishing the eventgrid events to a custom topic. This was explained in Azure-SDK-Python-GitHub repo.
  Python code as below:

  ```
    import os
    from random import randint, sample
    import time

    from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
    from azure.eventgrid import EventGridPublisherClient, EventGridEvent

    key = os.environ["EG_ACCESS_KEY"]
    endpoint = os.environ["EG_TOPIC_HOSTNAME"]

    #authenticate client
    credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    client = EventGridPublisherClient(endpoint, credential)
    services = ["EventGrid", "ServiceBus", "EventHubs", "Storage"]    #possible values for data field

    def publish_event():
        #publish events
        for _ in range(3):

            event_list = []     #list of events to publish
            #create events and append to list
            for j in range(randint(1, 3)):
                sample_members = sample(services, k=randint(1, 4))      #select random subset of team members
                event = EventGridEvent(
                        subject="Door1",
                        data={"team": sample_members},
                        event_type="Azure.Sdk.Demo",
                        data_version="2.0"
                        )
                event_list.append(event)

            #publish list of events
            client.send(event_list)
            print("Batch of size {} published".format(len(event_list)))
            time.sleep(randint(1, 5))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        publish_event()
  ```